# Cardinality of Power Functions Question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How many elements does each of these sets have where $a$ and $b$ are distinct elements?

$$\wp(\{a,b,\{a, b\}\})$$

and

$$\wp(\wp(\wp(\varnothing)))$$

I cannot understand how the power function works in here.

Answer (score 1):

The power set of $A$ is the set of all subsets of $A$, namely: $$\wp(A)=\{B\mid B\subseteq A\}.$$

In the case that $A=\{a,b,\{a.b\}\}$, we have that $A$ has three *elements*. An easy way to see this is to denote by $c$ the set $\{a,b\}$, then $A=\{a,b,c\}$. Can you count the subsets of $A$?

In the second case you just apply the power set three times to the empty set. The first application is $\wp(\varnothing)=\{\varnothing\}$. Now you should be able to calculate the second application, $\wp(\wp(\varnothing))$ and the third one.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\{a,b\}$ is distinguishable from either $a$ or $b$, you can think of the first as being a power set of three elements.  So, for $A=\{a,b,\{a,b\}\}$ you have $|\mathscr{P}(A)|=2^{|A|} = 8$

As for the other one, $\mathscr{P}(\emptyset) = \{\emptyset\}$, which agrees with our earlier statement since $2^0 = 1$.  Doing this again would give $\mathscr{P}(\mathscr{P}(\emptyset)) = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$.  Doing it once more will give you $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\}, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\}$, which gives us four elements.

It is important to note that the number of brackets around an element makes it distinguishable from similar elements with different number of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

What's perhaps confusing in the first one is that it's tempting to think that, hey, since $\{a,b\}$ is in the the set, and since $\{a,b\}$ is also a subset of the set, that's going to cause a problem in the power set, and leave us with only 7 elements or something like that. This isn't a problem, however, since, when we represent that *singleton* for each element, we end up with $\{\{a,b\}\}$ in the power set stemming from $\{a,b\}$ being in the set alongside $\{a,b\}$ in the powerset, since that is a subset - but $\{\{a,b\}\}$ and $\{a,b\}$ are distinct, so there's no issue.

For the empty set, we end up with the set which contains the empty set for the powerset - that is $\{\{\}\}$, since every set is a subset of itself. You can just treat $\{\}$ as if it were a variable or anything else and take the power set from there.

More generally, there *must* always be $2^{|A|}$ elements in the powerset of $A$ for any finite set $A$;  essentially, for each element $s\in A$, to construct a subset of $A$, we choose whether to include $s$ in the given subset. We get $|A|$ such choices with $2$ options each and every outcome is distinct and represented by this process (since it can always be recognized, given the subset, which $s$ were chosen to be in it) - thus, it is simple to show that the cardinality of the powerset is $2^{|A|}$.